# Don't understand why I keep getting this TypeError about unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python

I keep getting this error:

```
File "C:/Users/EEWOR/OneDrive/Documents/httgh.py", line 15, in s
    total+=((powerfirst))/(factfirst)*(x**(firstxpower))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'function'
```

When running this code:

```
def s(x) :
    def factfirst(n):
        initalvalue=1
        for y in range(1,2*x):
            initalvalue=initalvalue*y
        return (factfirst)
    def powerfirst(n) :
        (-1)**(n-1)
        return (powerfirst)
    def firstxpower(n) :
        (2*n)-1
        return (firstxpower)
    for n in range(1,x+1):
        total=0
        total+=((powerfirst))/(factfirst)*(x**(firstxpower))
    return sum(total)
print(s(5))
```

Comment: You are not calling your functions. E.g. `powerfirst(n)`, `factfirst(n)`, ...

Comment: And if you make that correction, you will still get the same error, because your functions return functions, not numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def s(x) :
    def factfirst(n):
        initalvalue=1
        for y in range(1,2*x):
            initalvalue=initalvalue*y
        return (factfirst) // you are returning function not a value or result
    def powerfirst(n) :
        (-1)**(n-1)
        return (powerfirst) //you are returning function not a value or result
    def firstxpower(n) :
        (2*n)-1
        return (firstxpower) //you are returning function not a value or result
    for n in range(1,x+1):
        total=0
        total+=((powerfirst))/(factfirst)*(x**(firstxpower))// you are dividing functions because your returns return functions
    return sum(total) //cannot sum a single value
print(s(5))
```

This nested function usage is not good, hard to read.
Try this:

```
def factfirst(n):
    initalvalue=1

    for y in range(1,2*n):
        initalvalue=initalvalue*y
    return initalvalue

def powerfirst(n) :
    return (-1)**(n-1)

def firstxpower(n) :
    return (2*n)-1

def s(x) :
    for n in range(1,x+1):
        total=0
        total+=(powerfirst(n)//factfirst(n)*(x**firstxpower(n)))
    return total
print(s(5))
```

this is working and you can make further changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help that worked to get rid of the error. Now I am trying to get the correct answer with s(2) = .90929, I keep getting -1.33 or for s(5) = -.958 where I  keep getting 5.38

Comment: @PhilS I will try to help you but before that, you should accept and upvote my answer so the question can be closed then because what you are asking now is a totally different question.

Comment: Just accepted the answer, I don't know if there is anything else I need to do

Comment: If you upvote it, that would be great too. Also I answered your other question as well take a look

Comment: right next to my question there is up and down buttons. Where you accepted the answer

Comment: I hit the up arrow but because I have less than 15 it is recorded but don't change the score is what came up.